# RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm writing a program which starts one thread to generate "work" and add it to a queue every N seconds. Then, I have a thread pool which processes items in the queue.

The program below works perfectly fine, until I comment out/delete line #97 (`time.sleep(0.5)` in the main function). Once I do that, it generates a RuntimeError which attempting to gracefully stop the program (by sending a SIGINT or SIGTERM to the main process). It even works fine with an extremely small sleep like 0.1s, but has an issue with none at all.

I tried researching "reentrancy" but it went a bit over my head unfortunately.

Can anyone help me to understand this?

**Code:**

```py
import random
import signal
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import Future, ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime
from queue import Empty, Queue, SimpleQueue
from typing import Any


class UniqueQueue:
    """
    A thread safe queue which can only ever contain unique items.
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._q = Queue()
        self._items = []
        self._l = threading.Lock()

    def get(self, block: bool = False, timeout: float | None = None) -> Any:
        with self._l:
            try:
                item = self._q.get(block=block, timeout=timeout)
            except Empty:
                raise
            else:
                self._items.pop(0)
                return item

    def put(self, item: Any, block: bool = False, timeout: float | None = None) -> None:
        with self._l:
            if item in self._items:
                return None
            self._items.append(item)
            self._q.put(item, block=block, timeout=timeout)

    def size(self) -> int:
        return self._q.qsize()

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        return self._q.empty()


def stop_app(sig_num, sig_frame) -> None:
    # global stop_app_event
    print("Signal received to stop the app")
    stop_app_event.set()


def work_generator(q: UniqueQueue) -> None:
    last_execution = time.time()
    is_first_execution = True
    while not stop_app_event.is_set():
        elapsed_seconds = int(time.time() - last_execution)
        if elapsed_seconds <= 10 and not is_first_execution:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
        last_execution = time.time()
        is_first_execution = False
        print("Generating work...")
        for _ in range(100):
            q.put({"n": random.randint(0, 500)})


def print_work(w) -> None:
    print(f"{datetime.now()}: {w}")


def main():
    # Create a work queue
    work_queue = UniqueQueue()

    # Create a thread to generate the work and add to the queue
    t = threading.Thread(target=work_generator, args=(work_queue,))
    t.start()

    # Create a thread pool, get work from the queue, and submit to the pool for processing
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
    futures: list[Future] = []
    while True:
        print("Processing work...")
        if stop_app_event.is_set():
            print("stop_app_event is set:", stop_app_event.is_set())
            for future in futures:
                future.cancel()
            break
        print("Queue Size:", work_queue.size())
        try:
            while not work_queue.empty():
                work = work_queue.get()
                future = pool.submit(print_work, work)
                futures.append(future)
        except Empty:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.5)

    print("Stopping the work generator thread...")
    t.join(timeout=10)
    print("Work generator stopped")
    print("Stopping the thread pool...")
    pool.shutdown(wait=True)
    print("Thread pool stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop_app_event = threading.Event()
    signal.signal(signalnum=signal.SIGINT, handler=stop_app)
    signal.signal(signalnum=signal.SIGTERM, handler=stop_app)
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you called the `print()` in the signal handler, `stop_app()`.

A signal handler is executed in a background thread in C, but in Python it is executed in the main thread. (See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers).) In your case, while executing a `print()` call, another `print()` was called, and the term 'reentrant' fits perfectly here. And the current IO stack prohibits a reentrant call.(See [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c#L260) if you are interested.)

You can remedy this by using the `os.write()` and the `sys.stdout` like the following.

```
import sys
import os
...
def stop_app(sig_num, sig_frame):
    os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), b"Signal received to stop the app\n")
    stop_app_event.set()
```

Comment: Why does this issue only seem to happen when I remove the time.sleep() from the main function? Also, would the same issue appear when using a log.Logger()?

Comment: If you put the ```time.sleep()```, it will happen less likely because you should hit the ctrl-c at an instant that a ```print()``` call is being executed. And it will happen when you are using the ```Logger```.

Comment: Marked as correct as it fixed the issue - thought I'm still not entirely sure why it works if I'm honest. I will just avoid any printing/logging in the signal handler function. Cheers!

Comment: The above workaround works because ```os.write()``` directly calls the native API(a thin wrapper around the system call), bypassing the Python IO stack.